# Does datetime.isoformat() really conform to ISO-8601?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime, iso8601

According to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat), `datetime.toisoformat()` returns a string representing the date and time **in ISO 8601 format**, but the output format string may have UTC offset part formatted as `+HH:MM[:SS[.ffffff]]`. I looked and looked but I couldn't find anywhere that `[:SS[.ffffff]]` is part of the standard, and some 3rd party tools fail to parse string formatted in this way. This includes `dateutil` package, to which official python docs refer as "more full-featured ISO 8601 parser". Can someone explain what is going on, is python straight out lying to us in the docs? ;)

If I'm right, I guess python's docs should be updated to mention this, but another question then would be how to properly detect that given datetime object can be represented as valid ISO 8601 string. There is always the dirty option to check the output string but I wonder if something more elegant exists :) I tried:

1. `(dt.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 60).is_integer()` is simple but I don't really trust checking how much float is close to integer in this way.
2. `dt.utcoffset().microseconds == 0 and dt.utcoffset().seconds % 60 == 0` seems less error prone but I am not sure if it's right according to modular arithmetic.

Any better ideas?

Thanks for help!

Comment: No, the Python docs are not lying to you, the standard allows for seconds to include a decimal fraction which is what you are referring to (it's not the timezone/offset)

Comment: @IainShelvington not sure if I misunderstand you :) Full pattern returned by `isoformat()` specified in Python docs is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.ffffff+HH:MM[:SS[.ffffff]]`. My question refers to the part **on the right side of +**, which in my understanding **is** the timezone/offset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Java have support for time zone offsets with seconds precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810861/why-does-java-have-support-for-time-zone-offsets-with-seconds-precision)

Comment: @JasonS while this answer provided a nice explanation on why sub-minute offsets exist, I've selected the answer below as it's quoting the standard and confirming problems with python docs for `datetime.isoformat`. Mentioned the your answer in the comment though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO 8601 only permits UTC offsets using hours and minutes. From the [spec](https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/iso-tc154-wg5_n0038_iso_wd_8601-1_2016-02-16.pdf):

> 4.2.5.2 Local time and the difference from UTC
>
> ...
>
> The difference between the time scale of local time and UTC shall be
> expressed in  hours-and-minutes, or hours-only independent of the
> accuracy of the local time expression associated  with it.

So you're correct that [datetime.isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) doesn't always produce ISO 8601 compatible UTC offsets.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the source! Also answer to [Why does Java have support for time zone offsets with seconds precision?][https://stackoverflow.com/a/55810943/4080347] (mentioned by Jason S above provides explanation on why sub-minute resolution exists.